# Inline div's rows messed up

Tags: html, css

I'm having an issue that I don't know why is this, but I created 3 ids on CSS named first, second, and third and aligned them to left to be all inline with a 320px width. Now I'm trying to put the same divs on a second row inline as well but they are messing up. The second row starts in the middle of the page, and only the third one displays the right way. The first one starts on the left, the next one starts in the middle of the page, and the next one starts on the left as well and so on...

Here's the JSFiddle file: [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/vyxN4/1/)

You have to expand the **Result** box to the left to the max width so you can see what I'm talking about.

**html:**

```
<a href="#">
    <div id="first" align="left"><img src="http://www.main-hosting.com/hostinger/welcome/index/folder.png"><strong> Empty-Field/</strong></div>
    <div id="second">-</div>
    <div id="third" align="right">Last Update - January  0, 2014 00:00:00</div>
</a>

<a href="#">
    <div id="first" align="left"><img src="http://www.main-hosting.com/hostinger/welcome/index/folder.png"><strong> Empty-Field/</strong></div>
    <div id="second">-</div>
    <div id="third" align="right">Last Update - January  0, 2014 00:00:00</div>
</a>
```

**CSS:**

```
#first {
    width:320px;
    float:left;
}
#second {
    width:320px;
    float:left;
}
#third {
    width:320px;
    float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use classes instead of ids**, chances are your browser doesn't like your invalid markup. IDs are for unique elements used once. Classes are for multiple use.

You also have to handle the float properly. By adding a `clear: both;` after each line you stop this "second row in the middle"-thing.

Try this:

```
<a href="#">
    <div class="first" align="left"><img src="http://www.main-hosting.com/hostinger/welcome/index/folder.png"><strong> Empty-Field/</strong></div>
    <div class="second">-</div>
    <div class="third" align="right">Last Update - January  0, 2014 00:00:00</div>
</a>

<br class="clear" />

<a href="#">
    <div class="first" align="left"><img src="http://www.main-hosting.com/hostinger/welcome/index/folder.png"><strong> Empty-Field/</strong></div>
    <div class="second">-</div>
    <div class="third" align="right">Last Update - January  0, 2014 00:00:00</div>
</a>
```

And CSS:

```
.first {
    width:320px;
    float:left;
}
.second {
    width:320px;
    float:left;
}
.third {
    width:320px;
    float:left;
}
.clear {
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: Yes it worked. Maybe it could be by not adding clear after each row though. Thanks a lot ;)

Comment: Glad it helped, please consider accepting the answer. :) PS: You can play around with float as you like, but this is common practice.

Answer (score 3):

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/vyxN4/6/

```
<a class="fll" href="#">
    <div id="first" align="left"><img src="http://www.main-hosting.com/hostinger/welcome/index/folder.png"><strong> Empty-Field/</strong></div>
    <div id="second">-</div>
    <div id="third" align="right">Last Update - January  0, 2014 00:00:00</div>
    </a><div class="clear"></div>
<a class="fll" href="#">
    <div id="first" align="left"><img src="http://www.main-hosting.com/hostinger/welcome/index/folder.png"><strong> Empty-Field/</strong></div>
    <div id="second">-</div>
    <div id="third" align="right">Last Update - January  0, 2014 00:00:00</div>
</a><div class="clear"></div>
<a class="fll" href="#">
    <div id="first" align="left"><img src="http://www.main-hosting.com/hostinger/welcome/index/folder.png"><strong> Empty-Field/</strong></div>
    <div id="second">-</div>
    <div id="third" align="right">Last Update - January  0, 2014 00:00:00</div>
</a><div class="clear"></div>
<a class="fll" href="#">
    <div id="first" align="left"><img src="http://www.main-hosting.com/hostinger/welcome/index/folder.png"><strong> Empty-Field/</strong></div>
    <div id="second">-</div>
    <div id="third" align="right">Last Update - January  0, 2014 00:00:00</div>
</a><div class="clear"></div>
<a class="fll" href="#">
    <div id="first" align="left"><img src="http://www.main-hosting.com/hostinger/welcome/index/folder.png"><strong> Empty-Field/</strong></div>
    <div id="second">-</div>
    <div id="third" align="right">Last Update - January  0, 2014 00:00:00</div>
</a>
```

css

```
#first, #second, #third, .fll {
  float:left;
}

.clear:{
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: Float is ok, but also same ids used multiple times which is wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes it was `clear:both;` missing like @Heanz said. And already changed the ids to classes.

Answer (score 2):

You have to change your layout in my opinion in table like this:

**html**

```
    <div id="tableCont">
<div class="tableCol">    
<a href="#">
    <div class="first" align="left"><img src="http://www.main-hosting.com/hostinger/welcome/index/folder.png"><strong> Empty-Field/</strong></div>
    <div class="second">-</div>
    <div class="third" align="right">Last Update - January  0, 2014 00:00:00</div>
</a>
    </div>    
    <div class="tableCol">  
<a href="#">
    <div class="first" align="left"><img src="http://www.main-hosting.com/hostinger/welcome/index/folder.png"><strong> Empty-Field/</strong></div>
    <div class="second">-</div>
    <div class="third" align="right">Last Update - January  0, 2014 00:00:00</div>
</a>
    </div>
        <div class="tableCol">  
<a href="#">
    <div class="first" align="left"><img src="http://www.main-hosting.com/hostinger/welcome/index/folder.png"><strong> Empty-Field/</strong></div>
    <div class="second">-</div>
    <div class="third" align="right">Last Update - January  0, 2014 00:00:00</div>
</a>
<a href="#">
    <div class="first" align="left"><img src="http://www.main-hosting.com/hostinger/welcome/index/folder.png"><strong> Empty-Field/</strong></div>
    <div class="second">-</div>
    <div class="third" align="right">Last Update - January  0, 2014 00:00:00</div>
</a>
<a href="#">
    <div class="first" align="left"><img src="http://www.main-hosting.com/hostinger/welcome/index/folder.png"><strong> Empty-Field/</strong></div>
    <div class="second">-</div>
    <div class="third" align="right">Last Update - January  0, 2014 00:00:00</div>
</a>
    </div>
    </div>
```

**css**

```
.first {
  width:320px;
    display:table-cell;
}
.second {
  width:320px;
    display:table-cell;
}
.third {
  width:320px;
    display:table-cell;
}

#tableCont{
    display:table;
}

.tableCol{

}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vyxN4/11/)

Comment: Never use the same id more than once!

Comment: It was from the source. Keeped the same. Dunno why he used the same id's. Changing with classes

Answer (score 2):

```
    try clearfix in your code to clear the float blocks
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aashi/vyxN4/13/

or use display:inline-block in place of float http://jsfiddle.net/aashi/vyxN4/14/

you can remove "align:left from html"